# How to stop inserting values by input?

Tags: c

If the user has to insert a number of values and then they want to stop how can I do?

For example the user has to insert float values but if they insert a letter the loop stops. How can I create something like this:

```
for(;;){
    scanf("%f", &n);
    if(!isdigit(n))
         break;
}
```

Comment: It is strongly advised not to use `scanf` for interactive input. Use `fgets` and then use `sscanf`.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` is a poor choice for interactive user input. Especially because if the user types something that `scanf` does not expect, that input stays in the internal input buffer and will most likely cause trouble in the following `scanf`s further in the program.

I'd go for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  float n;
  char input[100];
  for (;;) {
      fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    if (sscanf(input, "%f", &n) != 1)
      break;

    printf("User input = %f\n", n);
  }

  printf("Last line entered by user: %s", input);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scanf` return value to break the loop.

**Example:**

```
for(;;){
     if(scanf("%f", &n) != 1)
         break;
}
```

`scanf` will return 1 if it successfully read the float.

Comment: This won't work if there will be further `scanf`s after the `for` loop. `scanf` is really not the right choice for interactive input.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with this code... I think it will work fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  float n;
  int check = 0;
  for( ;; ) {
    check = scanf("%f", &n);
    if (check != 1) break;
    printf("%f\n ", n);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This won't work if there will be further `scanf`s after the for loop. `scanf` is really not the right choice for interactive input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this very simple syntax, if you are expecting query type inputs where there's no need to remember the values

```
    float n;
    while(scanf("%f",&n)){
    printf(" %f",n);
    }
```

This will break on a character input.
If you need more precautions use Jabberwocky's answer.